# xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader giving null on Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to create some **xml** content in my web application.
For that i have used JAXB.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(QueryRequest.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                queryRequestXml.getBytes()));

        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        QueryRequest queryRequest = (QueryRequest) jaxbUnmarshaller
                .unmarshal(xsr);
```

The problem i am facing is that in JBOSS,Tomcat it works fine.But as soon as i move my application to Weblogic i get **xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);** as **null**.

Any idea on how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that wrapping the input stream into `StreamSource` is causing the problem. After dropping it your code becomes:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(QueryRequest.class);
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(queryRequestXml.getBytes());
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
```

And it should work now!